# in EditText cannot be typed in android

Tags: android

hi all
i have TextView and EditText in my xml but i cannot type in EditText.this my xml code and rounded rectangle background xml code.

```
<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip">

 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView android:text="first"  android:textColor="#686868"
    android:id="@+id/lable" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/r_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial" />
</LinearLayout>

<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#ababab" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView android:text="middle"  android:textColor="#686868"
    android:id="@+id/lable" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/r_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial" />
</LinearLayout>

    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#ababab" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView android:text="Last"  android:textColor="#686868"
    android:id="@+id/lable" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/r_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial" />
</LinearLayout>


<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#ababab" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView android:text="DOB"  android:textColor="#686868"
    android:id="@+id/lable" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/r_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial" />
</LinearLayout>


<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#ababab" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView android:text="DOR"  android:textColor="#686868"
    android:id="@+id/lable" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/r_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial" />
</LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

rounded rectangle background coding

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
 <stroke android:width="3dp" color="#ffff8080"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp"
            android:color="#ababab" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your EditText fields have the same ID. That would be the first thing i'd change.

If that doesn't help: remove all extra things just to have a basic textfield, and re-add them to see where the problem is. So start with 1 `EditText` like this:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/this-is-unique" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp" />
```

And work your way up from there.

Edit: try to remove that rounded backgroud also. Just to be sure. Just add one very simple edittext to make sure it is not some other piece of your code doing this. No extra linearlayouts or anything, just make your xml as simple as possible. If it still doesn't work, you know you have to look for something else, if it does, start re-adding your views and settings to find the culprit.

Comment: hi  i  changed all EditText id as unique and changed as following but i am still cannot be typed .  <EditText android:id="@+id/middle" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp" />

i draw rounded rectangle for background for root linearlayout. i thing is make problem. i give that rounded rectangle background coding by editing my question please help me.

Comment: Please check out how your question looks while editting (it's below the edit field), and use the `{}` button for code. It'll be a lot clearer if half the XML isn't hidden :) .. I've fixed it for you now